# Pushing Headers and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, http-headers

I have a script that forces a download and I make a call to this via Javascript. However, the dialog box doesn't pop up, here is the download.php script:

```
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
// change, added quotes to allow spaces in filenames, by Rajkumar Singh
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($properFilename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile("$filename");
exit();
```

Here is the Javascript (using JQuery):

```
///force download
           $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "download.php",
           data: 'file=' + msg + '&properFilename=' + properFileName,
           success: function(msg){

              window.location.href = msg;

         });//ajax
```

This redirects my browser to another page rather than showing the down dialog box.

I know the JS variable msg contains the file with the right headers but I don't know what to do with it to get it to display the download dialog box.

Thanks all

p.s. Didn't know where to put this thread JS or PHP.

### EDIT:

I have the right approach I am sure of that :) - A user comes to my site, they fill in a form and they press submit. After a few seconds their fle should show up in a dialog box that they can download. To do this:

I make an AJAX call to get the file and download it. I use the PHP script to send the headers. Now all I need is a way to get the dowload dialog box to show up!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not showing the dialog box for the very fact that its an Ajax call.

```
window.location.href = msg;
```

Thats what's redirecting you. I don't think you need an ajax call here, just call the page normally with an href link.

**edit**

If you want the form to submit and show the dialog box for the download, do this:

```
<script>
function showDialogBox(form) {
    form.submit();
    window.location.href = "/download.php?file=XXX&properFilename=XXX";
}
</script>
<form onsubmit="showDialogBox(this);">

</form>
```

Comment: I do need ajax, I need it show the download dialog box without reloading page.

Comment: just creating a link, if the headers are set correctly, wont reload a page.... <a href="/download.php">link</a>

Comment: Thanks, its not exactly what I wanted but it works i guess. I just it was automatic without user clicking a button.

Answer (score 0):

If it full download.php script I can't find in it variable $file (only a $filename) - but in JS you send a $file variable. Second: something wrong in JS - why you use such variable name `msg` in `data:` and in `success:`?

Comment: I changed the name of that variable, it wasn't causing any problems, just bad programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

My take is that this may be expected, as sktrdie notes. I can't test right now, but if you think about it: the user, per se, doesn't get any notification about AJAX stuff you're doing. Having suddenly such a message would be irritating.

I guess that if you create a (even hidden?) iframe on that page and redirect to that download URL that you would get that dialog. YMMV, HTH.

Comment: Its not a message, its a file they have requested.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't coded php for a while so I'm not sure if there's anything wrong with your code. But I think the problem is in your approach. You need to load download.php in a frame not as a response to an ajax call. So basically you need to form an invisible iframe in the document and point it to download.php whith the get parameters appended to the url.